# How do you add reporter label to istio custom metrics with IstioOperator

Tags: prometheus, metrics, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I created custom metrics with `IstioOperator` as such (example only in `inboundSidecar`, but I also add it for `outboundSidecar` and `Gateway`)

```yaml
 telemetry:
      v2:
        prometheus:
          configOverride:
            inboundSidecar:
              debug: true
              definitions:
                - name: proxy_latency_milliseconds
                  type: 'HISTOGRAM'
                  value: "(request.duration - duration(response.headers['x-envoy-upstream-service-time']+'ms')).getMilliseconds()"
              stat_prefix: istio
```

I want this `proxy_latency_milliseconds` to be differentiated based on whether it is in inbound sidecar, outbound sidecar, or gateway. For default istio metrics, there is label called `reporter`, but I can't find that label on this custom metrics. How do I get it?

I have tried adding a custom dimension label by name `proxy_type`, each with a different value such as:

```yaml
                - dimensions:
                    request_host: request.host
                    request_method: request.method
                    route_name: route_name
                    response_code_details: '(response.code_details == "via_upstream") ? response.code_details : "other"'
                    proxy_type: "inbound"
```

however, when I see the actual metrics, it is actually shown as "unknown" instead of "inbound" or "outbound" or "gateway".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reuse the reporter value, can you please try to add a label to your custom metric and add the $REPORTER there, as shown below?

```
definitions:
                - name: proxy_latency_milliseconds
                  type: 'HISTOGRAM'
                  value: "(request.duration - duration(response.headers['x-envoy-upstream-service-time']+'ms')).getMilliseconds()"
                  labels:
                    reporter: "$REPORTER"
```

Comment: That's nice to know, I'll try later. how I solved it was to add another single quote inside the double quotes. Such as "'inbound'" or "'gateway'"